# Inheritance and module pattern

Tags: javascript, inheritance, module-pattern

I'm trying to implement the inheritance with the module pattern in this way:

```
Parent = function () {

    //constructor
    (function construct () {
        console.log("Parent");
    })();

    // public functions
    return this.prototype = {

        test: function () {
            console.log("test parent");
        },


        test2: function () {
            console.log("test2 parent");
        }

    };
};


Child = function () {

    // constructor
    (function () {
        console.log("Child");
        Parent.call(this, arguments);
        this.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
    })();


    // public functions
    return this.prototype = {

        test: function()
        {
            console.log("test Child");
        }

    }

};
```

but I can't to call from child's instance the `test2()`.

```
var c = new Child();
c.test2(); // c.test2 is not a function
```

What I wrong?

Comment: [How to implement inheritance in JS Revealing prototype pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248655/how-to-implement-inheritance-in-js-revealing-prototype-pattern) explains in-depth how to use the module pattern and inheritance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not using the module pattern in the correct way. Somehow, your "constructor" is called as an immediately-invoked function expression ([IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)), and the module closure is not. It should be the other way round.

Also, you can't assign to `this.prototype`. To create the prototype object from which all instances will inherit, you will need to assign to the `prototype` property of the *constructor function* (the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) even pointed to the global `window` object in your case).

And you should return the constructor function, not the prototype object, from the IIFE as soon as you have it.

```
Parent = (function () {
    // constructor
    function construct () {
        console.log("Parent");
    };

    // public functions
    construct.prototype.test = function () {
        console.log("test parent");
    };
    construct.prototype.test2 = function () {
        console.log("test2 parent");
    };

    return construct;
})();


Child = (function () {
    // constructor
    function construct() {
        console.log("Child");
        Parent.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    // make the prototype object inherit from the Parent's one
    construct.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
    // public functions
    construct.prototype.test = function() {
        console.log("test Child");
    };

    return construct;
})();
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Now I would have another question: Is it possibile to add in Child a static function?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "static", there's no real equivalent to that in the dynamic JS language :-) However, you could assign a function to the `Child` constructor function object: `Child.method = function(){…};` (or inside the module closure, `construct.method = …;`)

Comment: with "static" I mean call a function without to create an istance of `Child`. Something like this `Child.myStaticFunction()`

Comment: It's not clear why this line :`Parent.apply(this, arguments);` is there. it does nothing in the relevant code.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: It does execute the parent constructor, as visible from the side effect `console.log("Parent");`. Of course, it actually does nothing, but it's there in case the parent will get extended in the future. Just a good practise to keep the code maintainable, and it does no harm :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
    console.log("Child");
    Parent.call(this, arguments);
    this.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
})();
```

`this` refers to `window`, because you wrapped your code into a function. Remove the wrapping function or pass `this` as argument.

Comment: Who passes `this` as `this`?

Comment: You said "*pass `this` as argument*", which seems useless. OK, I had assumed that you passed it as the thisArg, but even if not it won't matter - could you please post the code you thought of?

Comment: `(function (that) { Parent.call(that ... } (this))`

Comment: Ah, now I see. I didn't even spot the `Parent` call as the big mistake, but the `this.prototype` assignment.