# How to instantiate from a module as if it were a class with Module Pattern?

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns

It's my understanding the Javascript Module Pattern simulates classes found in class-based languages, but I haven't been able to find an example of an object being instantiated using this pattern. In Java, classes are instantiated like this:

```
var myClassInstance = new MyClass();
```

All the Module Pattern tutorials I've seen explain the creation of a module with this basic syntax:

```
var MyModule = (function(){
    var privateMember = 'foo';

    function publicMember() {
    }        

    return {
        publicMember: publicMember
    }
}());
```

1. How would I then create a new instance of `MyModule` in this example?
2. Are modules meant to be instantiated?
3. What's the proper way to instantiate an object using the Module Pattern?

Comment: you might want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9321429/1048572 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/15437040/1048572

Answer (score 3):

> How would I then create a new instance of `MyModule` in this example?

In your example you cannot create an instance of your module because it is a plain object.

> Are modules meant to be instantiated?

Most aren't meant to be but it's up to you if your module should be instantiated first in order to use it.

> What's the proper way to instantiate an object using the Module Pattern?

Classes can be 'emulated' in javascript like this:

```
var MyClass = (function(){
    function MyClass() {
    }

    var privateMethod = function() {};
    MyClass.staticMethod = function() {};
    MyClass.prototype.instanceMethod = function() {};

    return MyClass;
}());

var classInstance = new MyClass();
```

And modules or namespaces like this, just as in your example:

```
var MyModule = (function(){
    var MyClass = (function(){
        function MyClass() {
        }

        var privateMethod = function() {};
        MyClass.staticMethod = function() {};
        MyClass.prototype.instanceMethod = function() {};

        return MyClass;
    }());            

    return {
        MyClass: MyClass
    };
}());

var classInstance = new MyModule.MyClass();
```

These are very simple examples but this pattern can be very complex. Like this other example of a module that you must instantiate in order to use its classes:

```
var MyModule = (function() {

  /** Module constructor */
  function MyModule(arg0, arg1) {

    this.MyClass = (function() {

      /** Class constructor */
      function MyClass() {
        this.publicArg0 = arg0;
        this.publicArg1 = arg1;
      }

      var privateMethod = function() {};
      MyClass.staticMethod = function() {};
      MyClass.prototype.instanceMethod = function() {};

      return MyClass;
    }());

  };

  return MyModule;
}());

var moduleInstance = new MyModule('#some', 1324);
var classInstance = new moduleInstance.MyClass();

console.log(classInstance.publicArg0) // "#some"
console.log(classInstance.publicArg1) // "1324"
```

Comment: That last example seems to be an antipattern. "Instantiating" a module would imply that you could have multiple instances of it - yet your variables are static, and you must call `new MyModule` exactly once. Better make it a singleton object and give it an `.init(…)` method.

Comment: I have to admit I prefer factories over constructors when there's a) no instance state and b) no inherited properties to be shared, but +1 nonetheless

Comment: @Bergi I think a singleton would make the code a tiny bit longer. Actually, the way it is now looks dead simple, although it isn't, e.g. one can be confused on how `this`'s value changes if it is inside of which function.