# What is the proper way to declare javascript prototype functions calling helper functions

Tags: javascript, performance, prototypal-inheritance

I'm trying to determine what is the best practice for declaring helper functions used by a javascript "class". For example:

Method #1:

```
// closure issues?
function helper(param) {
  return compute(param);   
}

function HeavilyInstantiated() {}

HeavilyInstantiated.prototype.computeHard = function(params) {
   var someResult = helper(params.prop1);
   return someResult;
}
```

Method #2:

```
function HeavilyInstantiated() {}

// still, only one instance for all objects instantiated?
HeavilyInstantiated.prototype.helper = function(param) {
   return compute(param);  
}
HeavilyInstantiated.prototype.computeHard = function(params) {
   var someResult = this.helper(params.prop1);
   return someResult;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "closure issue"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement Revealing prototype pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248655/how-to-implement-inheritance-in-js-revealing-prototype-pattern)

Comment: What I meant by saying "closure issue" is that the helper function might be closured by every instance of HeavilyInstantiated. By maybe that's not the case- just gets pushed and popped off the stack??? Probably just "polluting" the global namespace.

Comment: No it's not in a closure - it is not in the function body of the `HeavilyInstantiated` constructor but outside. It's in the global scope indeed, and to avoid that pollution use the *revealing module* pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer method 3, declaring it as a property of the constructor:

```
function HeavilyInstantiated() {}

HeavilyInstantiated.helper = function(param) {
   return compute(param);  
}
HeavilyInstantiated.prototype.computeHard = function(params) {
   var someResult = HeavilyInstantiated.helper(params.prop1);
   return someResult;
}
```

You still have only one instance of the helper method, but it doesn't pollute the global namespace or the instances of HeavilyInstantiated (it is not on their prototype chain).

Comment: Right, this is my objective, only one instance of helper, not polluting the global namespace or current scope, and looks like you've got a bonus - not polluting the prototype chain as well. I'll dig into this. thanks.