# Creating inheritance on revealing modular pattern objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create some kind of inheritance between objects:

```
var foo = (function(){

    function doFooStuff(){
        console.log(arguments.callee.name);
    }

    return {
        doFooStuff: doFooStuff
    }

})();

var bar = (function(){

    $.extend(this, foo);

    function doBarStuff(){
        console.log(arguments.callee.name);
        doFooStuff();
    }

    return {
        doBarStuff: doBarStuff,
    }

})();

bar.doBarStuff();
bar.doFooStuff(); //<-- Uncaught TypeError: 
                  //Object #<Object> has no method 'doFooStuff'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wRXTv/

Why isn't `doFooStuff` accessible here? Would you recommend another approach than using `$.extend`?

Comment: When you do `$.extend(this, foo);` What are you trying to do? `this` represents the global object (that's usually `window` in the browser). Did you mean to call the second IIFE like a constructor using `new function(){` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement inheritance in JS Revealing prototype pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248655/how-to-implement-inheritance-in-js-revealing-prototype-pattern) (though that is for the prototype inheritance pattern only)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Oh, I thought it referred to `bar`. And no, I don't want to create a new instance, I just want "static" objects.

Comment: @Johan see @Bergi's answer for a link to a more detailed explanation on how `this` works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> $.extend(this, foo);
> ```

`this` is not the object which you return from the function below (in fact it cannot be since it's created after this call), but the global object - check [MDN's introduction to the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

For what you want to do, there are two ways:

- [Copy all properties](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) from `foo` onto your `bar` object after it is created:

  ```
  var bar = (function() {
      …
      return {…};
  })();
  $.extend(bar, foo);
  ```

  You can do that as well directly on the returned object:

  ```
      return $.extend({…}, foo);
  ```

  A variant of this pattern allows you to overwrite `foo` properties. Copy `foo` into an empty object, then write your `bar` properties to it:

  ```
      return $.extend({}, foo, {…});
  ```
- Use prototypical inheritance. [Create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) an object that inherits its properties from `foo`, and then write your `bar` properties to it:

  ```
      return $.extend(Object.create(foo), {…});
  ```

  Now when `foo` changes afterward, you still can access those new properties on `bar` (unless they're shadowed by own properties). Notice that `Object.create` might not be supported in legacy environments, but you can easily shim it.

---

As noted by @raina77ow, your `doBarStuff` function is flawed too. The `doFooStuff` function is not in the scope of your function, and you cannot change that. You never will be able to access the private declared functions and variables from the `foo` module, only those that are public - if you did need them, consider a different pattern or app design. However, `doFooStuff` is a property on the exported (public) `foo` object, from which bar inherits (regardless in which of the above demonstrated ways). Therefore, you can access it as a method of `bar` as well, usually by using `this.doFooStuff()`.

Comment: Thanks Bergi. Could you give a short explanation on the difference between `$.extend(Object.create(foo)...` and `$.extend(foo...` ?

Comment: `$.extend` does copy the properties it sees one the second (and further) arguments to its first argument, creating a *snapshot* and leaving two distince objects with similar properties pointing to the same values. Instead, `Object.create` does [true inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186244/what-does-it-mean-that-javascript-is-a-prototype-based-language), the resulting object does not have any properties on its own but looks them up on its prototype object *live*.

Comment: Notice I never extended `foo`, I used it as a source argument only. Written out: `var bar = {}; $.extend(bar, foo); $.extend(bar, {…})` vs `var bar = Object.create(foo); $.extend(bar, {…});`

Answer (score 5):

You attempt to work with revealing module as if it were a constructor. Hence an attempt to extend `this`, wrong for many reasons. The most glaring, I suppose, is that neither the function is used as a constructor (no `new`) nor its context is changed. In plain words, `this` just points to a global object here.

But that's not the only problem. Consider that part of your code:

```
function doBarStuff(){
  console.log(arguments.callee.name);
  doFooStuff();
}
```

Here `doFooStuff` won't be in the scope even if you somehow manage to extend `this`. ) Remember, the scope resolution doesn't involve the context object.

So what's the solution? Well, I often use aggregation in similar cases:

```
var foo = (function(){
    function doFooStuff(){
        console.log(arguments.callee.name);
    }
    return {
        doFooStuff: doFooStuff
    }
})();

var bar = (function(){
    var _super = foo;
    function doBarStuff(){
        console.log(arguments.callee.name);
        _super.doFooStuff();
    }
    // static parent: further changes on `foo` won't affect `bar`,
    // as $.extend takes the parent's current state
    return $.extend({}, _super, {
        doBarStuff: doBarStuff,
    });
    // dynamic parent: further changes on `foo` will affect `bar`,
    // as extended object now has `foo` in its prototype chain
    return $.extend(Object.create(_super), {
        doBarStuff: doBarStuff,
    });
})();
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dxv58/).

Yes, it's aggregation, not inheritance. But so what? I'm still able to get the main prize - removing code duplication AND I'm able to control the usage of parent functions within the child module.

Comment: I see. This wouldn't merge `foo` and `bar` though.

Comment: Check the update (and the fiddle). Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: Nice, didn't think about extending at the return statement. Why do you pass an empty object as the first argument to `extend`?

Comment: Because otherwise `foo` object (referred by `_super`within the function) will be changed too. Note that in this case further changes on `foo` will not affect `bar` (it returns a new object based on _current_ `foo` state). If you want it other way, use `return $.extend(Object.create(_super), {..})`, as in @Bergi example.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that **this** in $.extend(this,foo) refers to the **window** object and **not foo**. Anonymous function are run in window's context.

I would recommend using a **John Resig**  implementation of classical inheritance in javascript. 
http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/.

**Extract:**

```
var Person = Class.extend({
 init: function(isDancing){
 this.dancing = isDancing;
 },
dance: function(){
 return this.dancing;
 }
});

var Ninja = Person.extend({
 init: function(){
  this._super( false );
 },
dance: function(){
 // Call the inherited version of dance()
 return this._super();
},
 swingSword: function(){
  return true;
 }
});

var p = new Person(true);
p.dance(); // => true

var n = new Ninja();
n.dance(); // => false
n.swingSword(); // => true

// Should all be true
p instanceof Person && p instanceof Class &&
n instanceof Ninja && n instanceof Person && n instanceof Class
```

Comment: How is using John Resig's library a vanilla implementation?

Comment: Well, John Resig _is_ rather vanilla these days. )

Comment: -1. OP wants a singleton module pattern, `Class` is not what he needs. Inheritance can be done without classes (or a "class"ical pattern) in JavaScript, and it should be done so here.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: What I meant was it doesnt depend on any other library like jQuery. Not the right set of words i guess.

Comment: @SelvamPalanimalai: Yeah, a really *vanilla* approach would be not to use any library - your code depends on `Class`…

Answer (score 0):

It is because this is an anonymous function. This part of your function deceleration:

```
   var foo = (function(){

    function doFooStuff(){
        console.log(arguments.callee.name);
    }

    return {

        doFooStuff: doFooStuff
      }

   })();
```

Do you see that you are immediately invoking this function call and ultimately do not have access to `doFooStuff` within your return statement.

If you remove the anonymous function deceleration, it will work.