# What's wrong with the two ways to inherit from Revealing Module Pattern?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, revealing-module-pattern

I am trying to use RMP for most of my modules styles. However, I want to understand it completely with few questions below.

1. Object.create() seems working for RMP module inheritance. Am I missing something?

   ```
   var Obj = (function(){
       //do some constructor stuff
   })();

   var InheritingObj = (function(){
       //do some constructor stuff
   })();

   InheritingObj.prototype = Object.create(Obj.prototype);
   ```
2. [Define prototype and return to Obj works too](http://jsfiddle.net/d0n7kfmx/) Do I understand something wrong? It seems like prototype inheritance is working for RMP.

Comment: Depends on what your RMP modules are. Are they actual classes (constructors) or singleton objects? Your `Obj` doesn't look like a constructor, so inheritance doesn't make much sense there.

Comment: possible duplicate of either [Inheritance and module pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15437040/1048572) or [How to implement inheritance in JS Revealing prototype pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9248655/1048572) (or [Creating inheritance on revealing modular pattern objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18817218/1048572) for singletons)

Comment: @Bergi, here's a better example. http://jsfiddle.net/j3u7jnan/

Comment: That example doesn't make much sense actually. Are you trying to use `Object.create` for creating instances? If so, I had expected [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/j3u7jnan/1/)

Comment: Nothing in your code indicates use of Revealing Module Pattern. Am I missing something?

Comment: @I-LinKuo: Ok, le'ts [reveal `sam`](http://jsfiddle.net/j3u7jnan/2/) if you care for the looks of the pattern :-) You can usually mutate those module IEFEs quite freely without changing their meaning.

Comment: @Bergi, your latest example above and my 2nd example http://jsfiddle.net/d0n7kfmx/ in the question confirms that we can inherit from RMP. am I right? It's just yours is not prototype inheritance, mine is?

Comment: @Bergi, I should have clarified my remark was directed toward OP. Nothing in the OP's posted code has anything to do with Revealing Module Pattern. OP, using RMP doesn't prevent you from doing prototypal inheritance by throwing an error. Your fiddle isn't RMP -- RMP creates everything in the closure first and then references only the closure, and then reveals in the returned object literal. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906662/javascript-design-pattern-difference-between-module-pattern-and-revealing-modul/22918556#22918556

Comment: @user2734550: No, you inherit from an object or from a constructor ("class"). How that was constructed, or how your inheriting object is constructed, doesn't matter for inheritance; you don't inherit *from RMP*.

Comment: @I-LinKuo: OK, interesting distinction. Sorry I confused your comment with a response from OP.