# JavaScript inheritance with Require.js and the Revealing Module Pattern

Tags: javascript, inheritance, requirejs, revealing-module-pattern

### Question:

A seemingly simple question that I've been researching on and off the for past 2 weeks (please go easy as I'm new to all this!):

> How does one neatly implement inheritance in JavaScript when using Require.js and the Revealing Module Pattern?

---

### Example:

Here is an example module which is the base class of some type of '`Component`':

```
define('Component', [], function () {
   "use strict";

   var _privateVar = 10;
   var _doPrivateThings = function () {  /* do stuff */ };    
   var init = function () { /* do stuff */ };
   var update = function () {  /* do stuff */ };

   return {
      init : init,
      update : update
   };

});
```

Next I want to implement `CakeComponent` which should inherit everything from `Component` and allow me to edit/add methods and properties:

```
define('CakeComponent', ['Component'], function (Component) {
   "use strict";
   
   // Setup inheritance
   var CakeComponent = function() {}
   CakeComponent.prototype = new Component();

   // Add/edit methods/properties
   CakeComponent.prototype.newMethod = function () { /* do stuff */ };

   return {
      init : CakeComponent.init,
      update : CakeComponent.update,
      newMethod : CakeComponent.newMethod
   };

});
```

Firstly, I'm not sure if that makes complete sense, but secondly, my CakeComponent feels a bit gross because now I've got this `CakeComponent` redundancy everywhere and I've had to 're-reveal' the `init` and `update` methods.

I would really prefer something like this (I realise this doesn't make sense, it's really just pseudo-code):

```
define('CakeComponent', ['Component'], function (Component) {
   "use strict";

   this.extends(Component);
   var newMethod = function () { /* do stuff */ };

   return {
      newMethod : newMethod
   };

});
```

Any tips or suggestions would really be appreciated. Thanks.

---

### Further Details

- Maybe I should always be creating a class object within the `define` wrapper? I've seen people do this but it seemed unnecessary until I came across this problem.
- Would the `.call()` method on the function object be useful at all in this context? e.g. using `Component.call()`
- @Bergi please see below:

---

```
define([], function () {
    "use strict";

    var Component = function () {

        var _privateVar = 10;
        var _doPrivateThings = function () {  /* do stuff */ };
        this.init = function () { /* do stuff */ };
        this.update = function () {  /* do stuff */ };

    };

    return Component;

});
```

Comment: Have you had a look at [How to implement inheritance in JS Revealing prototype pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9248655/1048572) already?

Comment: `new Component();`  doesn't seem to work at all, your `Component` is a module object not a class constructor?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I have read that before, thanks, but my problem is really with requirejs, not just inheritance of the RVP, or protected variables. Hmm, I'll look into why it's not working, thanks

Comment: Do you actually want to have classes (instantiable multiple times), or module objects (singletons)? In the first case, you need to `return` the constructor from your `definer` functions, not an object literal as you currently do. If you want to have modules, what do you mean by "inheritance"?

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. I've added a point in the 'Further Details' question of my original post - but the example I added is still returning an object literal. How would I use RMP without returning an object literal? Do I have to use the `prototype` and forego private properties and methods if I want inheritance?

Comment: Ah, your new example returns the `Component` constructor, that's better. While you don't have to use the `.prototype`, you better should. You wouldn't return literals from the constructor, but just use `this`. No, you can still use private variables and methods in your constructor.

Comment: Oh, so to define private variables and methods I just leave off the `this`? (see updated code in Further Details)

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Now you can extend that pattern by using the prototype for methods that don't need to be privileged, and you can [inherit from the "class" as always](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10898859/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this model used before, called Universal Module Definition:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['Component'], factory);
    } else {
        root.CakeComponent = factory(root.Component);
    }
}(this, function (Component) {
    return {
        newMethod: function(){ /* do stuff */ }
    };
}));
```

You could try this, which is not "real" inheritance - in case it does not work - depending on environment, you might need to pass the base functions as well, which is a pity:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['Component'], factory);
    } else {
        root.CakeComponent = factory(root.Component);
    }
}(this, function (Component) {
    return {
        init: Component.init,
        update: Component.update,
        newMethod: function(){ /* do stuff */ }
    };
}));
```

You can read more to this Topic in this fantastic article about the [Universal Module Definition](http://dontkry.com/posts/code/browserify-and-the-universal-module-definition.html)

Comment: Oh wow, this looks sneaky - what do you mean by depending on the environment? As in browser vs node.js? Would it be better do define a class object (e.g. `var Component = function() { ... }`) within each module do you think?

Comment: @JoeRocc right, actually the implementation for node.js would look a bit different. Redefining Component in each module does not sound like a good idea. RequireJS should be able to hook on to this. Have a closer look at this article about the Universal Module Definiton: http://dontkry.com/posts/code/browserify-and-the-universal-module-definition.html.

Comment: @hexeri_software As far as I understood it, that article suggests not using the UMD, but rather picking a single definition and then using a build (browserify) to decide on the final module definition in post production? I'm not sure how that helps?

Comment: @JoeRocc The bottom part of the article is a matter of taste, i was referring more to the top. **BUT** try this: here are different global browser, node and commonJS solutions, all requireJS compatible: https://github.com/umdjs/umd

Comment: Thanks for your, though I'm not sure how this helps me with inheritance? @Bergi commented above that I may need to return a constructor from the `define` factory and (I think) use prototypes if I want to get proper inheritance. What are your thoughts on that? I didn't really realise that the 'module' paradigm is more singleton-oriented

Comment: @JoeRocc have not had the time to test your special case with UMD, it was just an idea for an approach that is commonly used and as far as i know, you can export anything (objects, functions, etc..) and not restricted to singletons. read more [here](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2014/what-is-amd-commonjs-and-umd/) and [here](https://spring.io/understanding/javascript-modules)