# Why is this Javascript prototype function called and who calls it with undefined?

Tags: javascript

Having this .js file:

```
var MyClass = function() {
};
MyClass.prototype = function myMethod(name) {
    // my statements here...
    // name is undefined here, but who calls this function and why?
    return {
        myMethod: myMethod
    };
}();
```

and a page which loads it:

```
<head>
    ... 
    <script src="myfile.js"></script>
</head>
```

**Question**

Why is this function called? As far as with my javascript limited knowledge I understand I am initializing a MyClass variable (which is containing a function) and adding a new function to the prototype. Obviosly I am missing something.

Comment: Please post the exact "*`// my statements here...`*"

Comment: Your own code calls it! Note the `()` after the function body.

Comment: It makes no sense to name the `myMethod` function that is part of that [revealing prototype IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248655/how-to-implement-inheritance-in-js-revealing-prototype-pattern/9321429#9321429)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gets called because it has `()` after it.

The first argument is undefined because there are no values between that pair of `(` and `)`.

You should write either

```
MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function myMethod(name) {
    // my statements here...
};
```

or

```
MyClass.prototype = (function(){
    function myMethod(name) {
        // my statements here...
    }
    return {
        myMethod: myMethod
    };
})();
```

Comment: wow, thx. (btw your answer proves, that the answer nothing to do with the statements inside... so it was a good decision to remove them and isolate the issue. Recursion is not playing, because who would call is the first caller?... anyway thx again.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as-is. `myMethod` is declared but because you end the declaration with `()` `myMethod` is executed on the spot and returns an object with a property pointing to itself that you cannot access, hence you get `undefined`. You are simply missing an important fact about Javascript Classes.

Classes must be **instantiated** before a prototype method written in that fashion is available to call. By calling `MyClass.myMethod()` (which is what I assume you are trying to do) you are trying to access the method on the Class `MyClass` rather than accessing the method of an **instance** of `MyClass` which is what I assume what you want. Simply create an instance of `MyClass` using the `new` keyword and `myMethod` will be available to you (see this [MDN doc page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) for more information). So without changing any of your code:

```
var myInstance = new MyClass
myInstance.myMethod('foo') // returns an object you are looking for
```